# How do I extract text from <span> elemant with timer?

Tags: jquery, html, parsing, jquery-selectors

I’m parsing a web page which contains a countdown timer, which means that the `<span>` element of this timer has different text content every second. All the other elements with static text can be parsed without a problem, but the element of the timer always returns nothing, an empty string, both with `.innerHTML` and `.textContent`. What I’m trying to obtain is the plain text value of the timer at the moment I’m calling the `.textContent`. (almost like a screenshot). Two questions:

1. How come the span element of the countdown doesn’t return any text content? Why is it behaving differently from all the other span elements?
2. Is there anything else I can do to obtain the text content of the span element besides `.innerHTML` and `.textContent`?

**Edit: code sample**

This is how I try to fetch the `.innerHTML` of the countdown timer:

```
var request = require('request');
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

request('example.com', function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

    const dom = new JSDOM(html);
    console.log(dom.window.document.querySelector('span.status__timer').innerHTML);
});
```

And this is the `<span>` element I'm trying to find:

[image: Span element]

A static `<span>` element such `span.status__count` returns the `.innerHTML` without a problem, but the timer returns an empty string. They seem identical: both of them have the same `React` identifier, so I highly doubt that's what's causing it.

Comment: `innerHTML` should work for the span... Are you completely sure you are accessing the correct span object?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by parsing the web page? Is it possible your parsing code is running too soon, before the content has been set in the span?

Comment: @MattClark yes, 100% sure. I’m selecting the span element by class name and there is only one span element with that name in the entire HTML document. The query selector returns an HTMLSpanElement but for some reason the `.innerHTML` is empty.

Comment: Can you simple try `console.log(theSpan)` and see what details you get about the object in the JS console?

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to scrape content from an external webpage? If so, you may be simply accessing the server generated content, before the timer has dynamically set the content for the span. A better way may be to figure out how the timer is generating the content for the span.

Comment: on which event do you try to get innerHtml ?? Please provide a code sample

Comment: @BlessonChristy I added a code sample.

Comment: @user1751825 It seems the content for the timer is generated with `React`, which is a library for updating the UI, but the weird thing is that the content for all the other static text is generated the same way. That wouldn't explain why `.innerHTML` returns something for all span elements except for the timer.

Comment: @MattClark I DID log the span element (see code), but all it returns is `HTMLSpanElement`. It doesn't provide me with any more details than that.